# RecyclerView inside CardView and Cardview height set as wrapping and it is not wrapping height

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

`RecyclerView` inside `Cardview` and `Cardview` height set as wrapping and it is   not wrapping height, its showing more space.

[image]

**XML Code**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/ns1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lcat1"
                    android:fillViewport="true"

                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_background_new_design"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <LinearLayout

                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:weightSum="1">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/bestdeal"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                        android:padding="5dp"
                                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                        android:text="DEALS"
                                        android:textColor="@color/primary_light"
                                        android:textSize="12sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/viewall"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                        android:gravity="right"
                                        android:padding="5dp"

                                        android:text="View All"
                                        android:textColor="@color/primary_light"
                                        android:textSize="12sp"

                                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_page2"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:background="@color/redmartredcolor"
                                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                    android:scrollbars="none" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: show me your code

Comment: updated please check

Comment: @Midhilaj Is it another `RecyclerView` under the first `RecyclerView` with those `CardView`s? Because there is a working fine `RecyclerView` at the the top of the layout

Comment: no it is not like that

Comment: recyclerview inside card view

Comment: @Midhilaj Try my answer. I have set the `RecyclerView` gravity to `bottom` and few more changes it should not be wrapped anymore.

Comment: i am checking please wait..

Comment: i can't eneble instent run because iam using sugar libary so it take 6 to 10 minut to run

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท not working your code

Comment: @Midhilaj I check your code its working correctly can you update complete XML code. I put your xml in one `Relative Layout` it working as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please manage card view content through below properties :

```
 app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
 app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
 app:contentPadding="0dp"
 app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp"
```

I hope to remove extra space from content.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following codes. I have made some changes and it should work fine.

**UPDATE:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ns1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_background_new_design"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bestdeal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="DEALS"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/viewall"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="View All"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_page2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/red"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**EDITED #2:**  (Simple and a new way to achieve)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ns1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_background_new_design"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bestdeal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="DEALS"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/viewall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="View All"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_page2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="@color/red"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: On the preview, everything looks fine which you should check on running. No hurries. If gradle takes time to build, check Gradle offline work from settings and it will be quick to build.

Comment: @Midhilaj I have made it a little bit easier and simple to achieve, please check the Edited #2. It works fine. Except, something went wrong with java codes which you should check java-kotlin side too.

Comment: I thing i resize recyclev image after displayed is there any problem to doing like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178255/discussion-between-w-and-midhilaj).

Answer (score 0):

Final soluction is

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Log.i("recy_",mRecyclerView.getHeight()+"");
                card_view_background.getLayoutParams().height=mRecyclerView.getHeight()+(mRecyclerView.getHeight()*10/100);
                card_view_background.requestLayout();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for your Cardview and it's parent LinearLayout.